# Update in mongodb, when Upsert is true, how to specify the order of the fields?

Tags: mongodb

```
    test:=testModel{
    Id:primitive.NewObjectID().Hex(),
    Type:"app",
    Count:1,
    Status:"ok",
    Desc:"desc",
    Ext:nil,
    Create:time.Now(),
    Update:time.Now(),
}
```

opts := options.Update().SetUpsert(true)

Use update When Upsert is true, I found that the order of the stored fields has changed...When I use the InsertOne function, it is stored in order

```
    {
    "_id": "5e01b2a068e26bb09c863723",
    "count": NumberLong("1"),
    "create": ISODate("2019-12-24T06:39:28.496Z"),
    "desc": "desc",
    "ext": null,
    "status": "ok",
    "type": "app",
    "update": ISODate("2019-12-24T06:39:28.496Z")
}
```

Comment: Which mongodb version are you using?

Comment: order of the fields does not matter in JSON Format.

Comment: Using mongodb4.2, golang 1.12

Comment: @mehta-rohan That may be true, but [MongoDB claims to preserve the field order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/) so it would seem that something else is at play here.

Comment: There [used to be a bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2592) around this that should have been fixed log ago (mongodb 2.6ish) but if you see and can repeat the issue you may want to add a ticket to their bug tracker since fixing that issue points to them wanting the order to stay preserved.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson  When using InsertOne, it can be stored in order,  Is it a map [string] interface conversion problem in golang?